# Independence: pi-system lemma proof in Probability with Martingales by Williams

Tags: probability, measure-theory

In paragraph 4.2 of Probability with Martingales by Williams the following lemma is stated ($(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability triple):

LEMMA. *Suppose that $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{F}$, and that $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are $\pi$-systems with*

$\sigma(\mathcal{I}) = \mathcal{G}$, $\sigma(\mathcal{J}) = \mathcal{H}$.

Then $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ are independent if and only if $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are independent in that

$P(I\cap J) = P(I)P(J), \; I \in \mathcal{I}, J \in \mathcal{J}$

The first 2 sentences of the proof read:

*Proof*. Suppose that $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$ are independent. For fixed I in $\mathcal{I}$, the measures (check that they are measures!)

$H \mapsto P(I \cap H)$ and $H \mapsto P(I)P(H)$

on $(\Omega, \mathcal{H})$ have the same total mass $P(I)$ and agree on $\mathcal{J}$.

---

My question is: What does it mean that these measures have a total mass P(I)? I interpret the statement as saying (for the first measure) that $P(I \cap \mathcal{H}) = P(I)$, but isn't this only true of $I \subseteq \mathcal{H}$? We aren't redefining $P$, are we?

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a measure space, then the *total mass* of $\mu$ is $\mu(X)$ (most commonly used in the context of finite measures). So, what your problem is saying is that the measure $Q_1(H) := P(I \cap H)$ has total mass $Q_1(\Omega) = P(I \cap \Omega) = P(I)$; the measure $Q_2(H):= P(I) P(H)$ has total mass $Q_2(\Omega) = P(I) P(\Omega) = P(I)$.

Comment: Thanks! What I missed is that (I think?) $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ contain $\Omega$ (because every sub-$\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ contains $\Omega$) :)